# C# TreeView limit dynamic child on each node

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes

[image: My Program]

([my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAzd0.jpg))

In my project I want to limit creating some nodes.

The user can add or remove dynamic nodes and children.
As in the above image, I have a parent called "screen" and a node called "program".

I have 3 objects called "videoObject","imageObject","textObject".

These are the rules I wish to apply:

1. the objects can only be added to each "program" node.
2. the objects don't have any children.
3. each program node cannot have a program as a child.

I need bind a list to this treeview to store screen node programs and each program node child's properties.

How can I apply this rule to treeview?

Comment: Pleas show us some code with what you have done until now. Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you created a Model for this ?
you could create a

```
private int _hierarchy = 0
public int Hierarchy
{
  get{return _hierarchy}
  set{_hierarchy = value}
}
```

before creation you check the higherarchy of the parent.

meaning if the hierarchy is 2, then you cant add a child to it.

Comment: By adding a Hierarchy, you can create much bigger tree views